# How to merge N files into one in sorted order?

Tags: java, external-sorting

I need to create a one huge sorted file from N small sorted files.

I have already made a research and found that External Sort algorithm is suitable.

But I have a memory constraint (limit of strings into memory < N), so I'm not able to load all first lines of each small file, sort them and after write down into an output file etc.

For instance, this link https://www.algosome.com/articles/how-to-sort-large-file.html isn't suitable because on merge stage he stores all first lines in memory.

Could you help me to figure out the best step by step algorithm or implementation for my case?

Thank you.

Comment: You can still partition it down further. i.e. assume if you have 10 files. you can work on sorting 5 files first --> create one sorted file and have 5 unsorted file, work on these 6 files on second pass

Comment: You don't have to open all the files at once. You use a multiphase merge, such as polyphase, balanced, ... These are well-known algorithms. See Knuth volume III for example.

Comment: yes, you  can just merge two at a time.

Comment: Two at a time is the very worst case. @RayTayek